# Search one word before character and one word after

Tags: regex

I want to get two words from a string, one before "__" and the other after.
To be an example:

```
'?o=-1' # Skip it
'?client__name=Client1&o=-1' # Should return client__name
'?o=-1&product__name=Product1+Test1' # Should return product__name
```

The nearest I was:

```
after:  (?:__).*[a-z]
before: (\S+?)__
```

I'm trying to use it in python

Comment: It depends what you consider as a "non string" or let say a "string separator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
[^\W_]+__[^\W_]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PCA6dZ/1) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B__%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B):

[image]

**Details**

- `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `__` - a `__` substring
- `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more letters or digits.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capturing group:

```
[&?]([^\W_]+__[^\W_]+)=
```

That will match:

- `[&?]` Match either & or ?
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^\W_]+__[^\W_]+` Match 1+ times a word char except an underscore, then `__` and again 1+ times a word char except an underscore
- `)` Close capturing group
- `=` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpFrqU/1)